# Rendering multiple altair charts in a single cell of a jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, altair

I see in the [troubleshooting guide](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html) to Altair that:

> 'If you are working in a notebook environment, the chart is only
>   displayed if the last line of the cell evaluates to a chart object'

I have a dictionary of several auto-generated altair charts. I want to show in one notebook cell, separately, all the charts I have created.   I would like to do something like:

```
for k in graphs:
   graphs[k].show()   #or the equivalent of 'show this chart'
```

How can I do the equivalent of this? Currently I can only render a single chart in a cell by evaluating a single chart.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`chart.display()`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html?highlight=display#altair.Chart.display):

```
for k in graphs:
   graphs[k].display()
```